# Create Database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a small progam in java page to create database for my application.Here is the  code.Database is at mysql.But is does not work for me.I think my code is correct.

```
private DataBaseSource dbSource = new DataBaseSourceImpl();
private Connection connection = null;
private Statement statement = null;
private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
private ResultSet resultSet = null;


/** Creates new form LoginScreen */
public LoginScreen() {
    initComponents();
    Container c =this.getContentPane();
    c.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    connection = (Connection) dbSource.getConnection();

    signInBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String uname = usrNameTxt.getText();
            char[] pword = pwordTxt.getPassword();
            String password = new String(pword);

            if(uname.equals("")&& password.equals("")){


            Util.showErrorMessageDialog("Please fill all the fields.");


            }else{

                if(uname.equals("") || uname.equals(" ")&& ! password.equals("")){


                 Util.showErrorMessageDialog("Login ID left blank");

            }else{

                if (password.equals("") || password.equals(" ")&& uname.equals("")) {

                Util.showErrorMessageDialog("Password left blank.");

                }else{

                authenticateLogin();

                }

            }


            }
        }
    });
}
public void authenticateLogin() {
    try {
        preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXIST macfast");
        preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginScreen.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }


}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new LoginScreen().setVisible(true);

        }
    });
}

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField pwordTxt;
private javax.swing.JButton signInBtn;
private javax.swing.JTextField usrNameTxt;
// End of variables declaration                   

}
```

This is my code example.But it does not create database named as macfast... shown in the above example. What happened for my program. Any one please help me

Comment: which database u going to connect

Comment: Generally speaking, this is not how SQL/JDBC works.  Normally, you create a connection to an existing database and manipulate the contents from within.  I'm not JDBC will allow you to create a database (or connect to a DB server without a database reference more importantly).  You might want to take a look at [JDBC Database Access](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/) for more details.  You could try and have a look at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/), although I've not used it...

Comment: i am trying to connect the mysql database....I am already connected the program with mysql.Select,update,delete quaries are work for me....But now i want to create a new database named 'macfast'

Comment: public class DataBaseSourceImpl implements DataBaseSource{

    Connection connection = null;
    public Connection getConnection()  {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/macfast","root", "pass");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DataBaseSourceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch () {
            Logger.getLogger(DataBaseSourceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
         return connection;
 }

Comment: please... dont't post that much code in your comments...

Comment: @SaranyaSaru u got ur output...

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `executeUpdate` instead of `executeQuery`.

```
Statement st = connection.createStatement();
st.executeUpdate("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS macfast");
st.close();
```

Comment: A prepared statement wouldn't really add much here since there are no parameters that need to be passed.

Comment: And a CREATE DATABASE is not something to repeat.

Answer (score 0):

Provide code for DataBaseSourceImpl(). What values are you trying to pass while trying to get the same. And why don't you just use DataSource instead. You will have to try and write a simpler program to test if your application is able to connect to the DB at all.

What error are you getting at the moment.

Comment: Couldn't find the add comment link on the actual post

however..

You are connecting to a DB which is already physically present. You have connected to 

"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/macfast"

Comment: you didn't find it, because you don't have the privilege yet